# MS Access Linked Combobox Is Updating The Source Table When I Want It To Be Read Only

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2016, ms-access-forms

Sorry for the lengthy explanation; I'm hoping the detail will help explain what I want to do.

In Access 2016 I want the user to be able to go into a form and select a combination of two values from one table (read only), then enter additional details in different fields that correspond to that combination.  When the record is saved, the additional details are saved in a different table along with the row ID that corresponds to the combination they selected.

For example, say I have a database for tracking a company's responses as to how they are meeting the requirements of various government regulations.  I have a table for regulations with fields for:

1. Row ID
2. Regulation Set, with static values stored in a value list (i.e. "HIPAA", "PCI DSS", etc.)
3. Regulation Number
4. Regulation Text

In this table, Regulation Numbers *may* be the same across Regulation Sets but the combination is unique so I have added a unique index on those two columns.

I have another table that captures the response information.  The Response table has a FK column that is linked to the row ID in the Regulations table.  There is a 1:M relationship between Responses:Regulations.

I want the user to be able to select the Regulation Set from a drop down list, then have a second drop down list that will display only the relevant Regulation numbers based on the Regulation Set.  They can then enter the relevant response data in other fields.

I created a form using the form wizard with combo boxes for the regulation set and regulation name, along with fields for the response data.  Linking the combo boxes works great.  I can select a Regulation Set, and then it limits the list of Regulation Numbers to only those that apply to that Regulation Set.  However, it tries to update the Regulation table when I want it to be read only.

Let's say I have these entries in the Regulation table for Regulation Set - Regulation Number
HIPAA - 1.0
HIPAA - 1.1
HIPAA - 1.3
PCI DSS - 5a
PCI DSS - 5b

I go into the form and select HIPAA in the first combo box.  The second combo box correctly shows the values 1.0, 1.1, 1.3.  I select 1.3 and do nothing else except try to close the form.  I get an error saying the record can't be saved because it will result in a duplicate value on the Regulations table.  If I remove the unique constraint and repeat the steps, I can close the form, but then when I go to the Regulations table, it has overwritten the data and now I have two HIPPA rows with the Regulation Name 1.3.

I want the form to only use the Regulations table as a lookup without any updates.  Once the user has a Regulation Set / Number combination and saves the response, I want to store the Regulation Row ID in the Response table.

I think this is related to the 1:M relationship between Regulation Sets and Regulation Numbers, so that when I select a Reg Set, it picks a record from the table; then I select the Reg Number which might be from a different row.  I'm OK with this mismatch on the form because when I save the response record, I can query the Regulation table for the row ID that corresponds to the values that were selected.  But I can't figure out how to keep it from trying to update the Regulation table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you need form/subform arrangement. Question too broad nor does it have code for analysis and therefore is not really suitable for SO.

Comment: Sounds like you have included both tables in form RecordSource and bound combobox to wrong field. Don't include Regulations table in form RecordSource.

Comment: I did indeed include both tables in form RecordSource.  I removed the Regulations table but now I can't get the first combobox to work.  The data source is a value list in the Regulations table rather than a 'select distinct'.  When I try to update the properties of the combo box, I can select 'Value List' but I don't see how to get the actual values from the list to show up.  I'm sure it is my lack of understanding; I'm trying to learn as I go.

Comment: If you use table or query as RowSource then RowSourceType must be Table/Query, not ValueList. This is basic Access functionality. Wouldn't hurt to spend a solid week studying an introductory tutorial book before trying to develop actual db. This is a new issue and can post a new question. Again, this is a design issue, not programming, and not really suitable for SO.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get help on another forum so I decided I would put the answer here in case it will help someone else.  In my case, the solution involves the pieces below.  #4 is what I was missing.

1) The Regulation Set (higher level) combo box should be unbound and have the record source equal to the Regulation Set Name and ID from the Regulation Set table.
2) The Regulation combo box is bound to the Response table (where there if a FK to the regulation table) and it uses the Regulation table as its record source.  The record source is restricted based on the value of the Regulation Set combo box.

3) The Regulation Set combo box has an After Update event to requery the Regulation combo box.
4) Then there is a bit of VBA code that is needed to get the Regulation Set combo box to show the right value based on the current value of the Regulation combo box.  This goes on the Form On Current event:

```
'Check if this is a new record; if not then there is a value
' in the Regulation combo box that can be used to determine
' the value to display in the Regulation Set combo box.
If Me.NewRecord = False Then
  ' Lookup the Regulation Set
  Me.cboRegSet = DLookup("[ID]", "tblRegulationSet", "[ID] =" & _
    DLookup("[RegulationSetID]", "tblRegulation", "ID=" & Me.RegulationID))
  'Requery the Regulation combo box
  Me.cboRegulation.Requery
  ' Get the "Regulation.ID" based on the foreign key "RegulationID"
  Me.cboRegulation = DLookup("[ID]", "tblRegulation", "ID=" & Me.RegulationID)
  Else
  'If this is a new record, blank out the Regulation Set
  Me.cboRegSet = ""
End If
```